# RDLC Doesn't Show Table Header When Use Grouping

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

I have an rdlc report use grouping. When report has not data, table header is not shown and only page header is visible. I try to use countRows() function to set row visibiliy but is didn't work too. Would you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, on a newly created table, the actual table headers should still be shown even if there are no rows, but any group headers will not be shown. Check to make sure that your headers are not in a group: i.e. they should not have a bracket on the left side of the row.

Copying my answer from a similar question a few weeks ago:

If a tablix (table, list or matrix) is connected to a dataset that returns no rows, then the tablix will not show any data rows (detail or other group rows.)

If you would like the tablix to show [data] rows when the dataset returns none, there are two easy answers:

1. Alter your dataset to always return a row: usually with a union.
2. Add a fake data row to your tablix header, but set the visibility of this row to an expression such as `=CountRows("DataSet6") <> 0`. This will hide the row when there are real rows returned by the dataset.

Comment: Thats it! Thanks alot for your helpful notices :)